# Use gmail SMTP server for my another email, in django

Tags: django, gmail

I have two emails, myemail@gmail.com and mymail@mydomain.com. I want to send email to users of my django app, from mymail@mydomain.com. I am using mydomain email, from my gmail account, using the add another account settings. But when I try to send email with the server as smtp.gmail.com,  I get SMTPAuthentication error. Is there any way I can use the gmail server? I cannot use smtp.mydomain.com , as there is no such host error, when I try telnet. What do I do now?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try sending an email as 'mymail@mydomain.com' after you log into google with 'myemail@gmail.com'  If your account has an alias for 'mymail@mydomain.com' it should work.  If that still fails you will need to use a service like mailchimp or sendgrid, or set up your own smtp server at smtp.mydomain.com.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you to use some service like mailchimp or sendgrid .